filename not matched in a newer version of unzip for windows
I use the same command with 2 versions of unzip :
unzip  sources.jar *.scala -d sources_extracted

With this version of unzip available on SourceForge, it works:
inflating: sources_extracted/path/to/file.scala

The version information is this one, it is an older version of unzip:
UnZip 5.51 of 22 May 2004, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir

modifiers:                                   -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -a  auto-convert any text files
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -aa treat ALL files as text
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -v  be verbose/print version info
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -$  label removables (-$$ => fixed disks)  -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -X  restore ACLs (-XX => use privileges)   -s  spaces in filenames => '_'
                                             -M  pipe through "more" pager
Examples (see unzip.txt for more info):
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer

However, recent versions of Git come with a more recent version of unzip :
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
  -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
modifiers:
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
  -U  use escapes for all non-ASCII Unicode  -UU ignore any Unicode fields
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer

When I try the same command, it raises the following error:
caution: filename not matched:  *.scala

I doubt that this could be a bug, so the question is, how should I adapt the syntax to the newer version ?
I tried the simple quotes or double quotes around *.scala but it didn't help.
Also, this infozip link on SourceForge seem to contains only the sources, not the binaries.

Do you need to use unzip, app with "recent" 2009 version? There are way more up-to-date solutions, including jar specificall made for jars.

No, actually, I'm just curious about why it's not working.

Quick look and it seems like a bug after all: https://github.com/LuaDist/unzip/blob/b2592fd6ac2dbf800130be3c64332317aff17f12/msdos/README#L49-L55
